# GPUImageDivideBlendFilter in GPUImage, what's corresponding filter for CIImage?

Tags: ios, gpuimage, ciimage

I have try this:

```
CIFilter *dodgeFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorDodgeBlendMode"];
```

to replace:

```
GPUImageDivideBlendFilter *divideBlendFilter = [[GPUImageDivideBlendFilter alloc] init];
```

but the effects are not same.

Answer (score 1):

## Builtin filter

Have you tried with `CIDivideBlendMode`?

```
CIImage *img1 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"]];
CIImage *img2 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"]];

CIFilter *filterBuiltin = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIDivideBlendMode"
                                     keysAndValues:@"inputImage", img1,
                                                   @"inputBackgroundImage", img2, nil];
CIImage *outputImageBuiltin = [filterBuiltin outputImage];
UIImage *filteredImageBuiltin = [self imageWithCIImage:outputImageBuiltin];
```

---

## Custom filter

I thought it would be fun to try to create a custom `CIFilter` based on an existing GPUImageFilter now that iOS8 allows us to do so. This should allow to translate any `GPUImageFilter` to its `CIFilter` counterpart.

Before starting it's worth checking out [*What You Need to Know Before Writing a Custom Filter*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_advanced_concepts/ci.advanced_concepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH9-SW1)  and [*Core Image Kernel Language Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIKernelLangRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004397)

We'll start by writing our custom kernel which will be very similar to the `GPUImageDivideBlendFilter` shader. The one exception is the control flow part that seems unsupported in the Core Image Kernel language which we'll workaround using the `*_branch1` and `*_branch2` multipliers.

Creating a CIFilter is simple:

1. Create a new `ImageDivideBlendFilter.cikernel` (your custom filter kernel) file to your Xcode project:

   ```
   kernel vec4 GPUImageDivideBlendFilter(sampler image1, sampler image2)
   {
       float EPSILON = 1e-4;
       vec4 base = sample(image1, samplerCoord(image1));
       vec4 overlay = sample(image2, samplerCoord(image2));

       float ra1 = overlay.a * base.a + overlay.r * (1.0 - base.a) + base.r * (1.0 - overlay.a);
       float ra2 = (base.r * overlay.a * overlay.a) / overlay.r + overlay.r * (1.0 - base.a) + base.r * (1.0 - overlay.a);

       // https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CIKernelLangRef/ci_gslang_ext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004397-CH206-TPXREF101
       // "Other flow control statements (if, for, while, do while) are supported only when the loop condition can be inferred at the time the code compiles"
       float ra_branch2 = step(EPSILON, overlay.a) * step(base.r / overlay.r, base.a / overlay.a);
       float ra_branch1 = step(ra_branch2, 0.5);

       float ra = ra1 * ra_branch1 + ra2 * ra_branch2;


       float ga1 = overlay.a * base.a + overlay.g * (1.0 - base.a) + base.g * (1.0 - overlay.a);
       float ga2 = (base.g * overlay.a * overlay.a) / overlay.g + overlay.g * (1.0 - base.a) + base.g * (1.0 - overlay.a);

       float ga_branch2 = step(EPSILON, overlay.a) * step(base.g / overlay.g, base.a / overlay.a);
       float ga_branch1 = step(ga_branch2, 0.5);

       float ga = ga1 * ga_branch1 + ga2 * ga_branch2;


       float ba1 = overlay.a * base.a + overlay.b * (1.0 - base.a) + base.b * (1.0 - overlay.a);
       float ba2 = (base.b * overlay.a * overlay.a) / overlay.b + overlay.b * (1.0 - base.a) + base.b * (1.0 - overlay.a);

       float ba_branch2 = step(EPSILON, overlay.a) * step(base.b / overlay.b, base.a / overlay.a);
       float ba_branch1 = step(ba_branch2, 0.5);

       float ba = ba1 * ba_branch1 + ba2 * ba_branch2;

       return vec4(ra, ga, ba, 1.0);
   }
   ```
2. Add the interface and implementation for your filter

   ```
   // ImageDivideBlendFilter.h
   #import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

   @interface ImageDivideBlendFilter : CIFilter

   @end


   // ImageDivideBlendFilter.m
   #import "ImageDivideBlendFilter.h"

   @interface ImageDivideBlendFilter()
   {
       CIImage *_image1;
       CIImage *_image2;
   }

   @end

   @implementation ImageDivideBlendFilter

   static CIColorKernel *imageDivideBlendKernel = nil;

   + (void)initialize
   {
       // This will load the kernel code which will compiled at run time. We do this just once to optimize performances
       if (!imageDivideBlendKernel)
       {
           NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
           NSString *code = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[bundle pathForResource: @"ImageDivideBlendFilter" ofType: @"cikernel"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
           NSArray *kernels = [CIColorKernel kernelsWithString:code];
           imageDivideBlendKernel = [kernels firstObject];
       }
   }

   - (CIImage *)outputImage
   {
       return [imageDivideBlendKernel applyWithExtent:_image1.extent roiCallback:nil arguments:@[_image1, _image2]];
   }

   + (CIFilter *)filterWithName: (NSString *)name
   {
       CIFilter  *filter;
       filter = [[self alloc] init];
       return filter;
   }

   @end
   ```
3. We're ready to use our newly created custom filter in our application

   ```
   - (void)filterDemo
   {
       CIImage *img1 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.jpg"]];
       CIImage *img2 = [[CIImage alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.jpg"]];

       [ImageDivideBlendFilter class]; // preload kernel, it speeds up loading the filter if used multiple times

       CIFilter *filterCustom = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"ImageDivideBlendFilter" keysAndValues:@"image1", img2, @"image2", img1, nil];
       CIImage *outputImageCustom = [filterCustom outputImage];

       UIImage *filteredImageCustom = [self imageWithCIImage:outputImageCustom];
   }

   - (UIImage *)imageWithCIImage:(CIImage *)ciimage
   {
       CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
       CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:ciimage fromRect:[ciimage extent]];
       UIImage *newImg = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];

       CGImageRelease(cgimg);

       return newImg;
   }
   ```

Builtin and custom filter produce the same result.

## Edit: Swift version

I made a sample project available on Github https://github.com/tcamin/CustomCoreImageFilteringDemo that shows how to make CIFiltering in Swift.

Answer (score 0):

The CIColorKernel code in the answer does not work; in fact, any attempt to pass more than one sampler object (image) to a kernel fails.

Answer (score 0):

Also—and I know this doesn't relate to the question, but I feel like this should be pointed out—the kernel code has one thing backwards, specifically, the premultiply-related functions. Unpremultiply any sampler (or color) object when working with the alpha channel independently from the remaining three; recombine them with premultiply when you have the finished product. Do neither if you are not changing or mixing or otherwise using two sampler (or color) objects in your calculations.